# How to call oracle function from a Korn Shell Script?

Tags: oracle, shell, scripting, ksh

I have a user defined oracle function that returns a number that can be greater than 255. I call that function from a shell script using sql plus, it returns the value, for eg 296, but the scripts accepts it as 40, which is because the script can only accept return codes from 0-255.

This is how i am currently receiving the value

```
echo ${PASSWORD} | sqlplus ${USERNAME}@${SID} @$SQL getnumber.sql $PARAM> ${LOG} 
number=$?
```

getnumber.sql has

```
set serveroutput on size 100
VARIABLE rc NUMBER;

call function_get_number('&2') into :rc;

print rc;
exit :rc;
```

How can i preserve the return value? Should i write it to a file? if so how/where

Answer (score 2):

Script getnumber.sh:

```
cat << EOF | sqlplus /S /nolog >${LOG}
conn ${USERNAME}/${PASSWORD}@${SID}
set serveroutput on size 100
VARIABLE rc NUMBER;

exec :rc := function_get_number('$PARAM');

SELECT 'RETVAL:' ||  :rc || ':' theval FROM dual;
EOF

RC=$( grep '^RETVAL:' ${LOG} | cutr -d":" -f2 )

echo $RC
```